# How to avoid long switch/case blocks in static methods

Tags: java, design-patterns

Lets say I have realy long `switch/case` block, which makes my inner me say 'it does not look good'

```
                        switch (option) {
                    case ERROR:
                        doSomething();
                        break;
                    case SUCCESS:
                        doSomething();
                        break;
                    case WARNING:
                        doSomething();
                        break;
                    case SUCCESS_WITH_WARNING:
                        doSomething();
                        break;
                    case SUCCESS_WITH_ERROR:
                        doSomething();
                        break;
                    case FATAL:
                        doSomething();
                        break;
                    case INFO:
                        doSomething();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
```

Remamber that we can always add more enums etc.
Let's say that method in `case` block are printing something to the console. So they are just `void`.

I was trying to use visitor, but it seems there are better choices, so with visitor it looks like that:

```
public enum ImportOption {

SUCCEEDED{

    @Override
    public void accept(ImportOptionVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitSucceededImport();
    }

},
FAILED{

    @Override
    public void accept(ImportOptionVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitFailedImport();
    }

},
WARNING{

    @Override
    public void accept(ImportOptionVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitWarningImport();
    }

};

public abstract void accept(ImportOption.ImportOptionVisitor visitor);

public interface ImportOptionVisitor{
    void visitSucceededImport();

    void visitFailedImport();

    void visitWarningImport();

}
```

And than in place of switch we got:

```
                        option.accept(new ImportOptionVisitor() {

                        @Override
                        public void visitSucceededImport() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void visitFailedImport() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void visitWarningImport() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
```

But it seems exaggerated even for long switches like 100 enums. I read a little about command pattern. But I am not sure how to implement it. Any ideas how to make a replace `switch` and make code a little more readable etc?

Ok, more information. This code is implemented in `Utils` class and the method which need this switch block looks like that:

```
public static void monitorDirectory(String zipDir, ImportOption option) {
        String dirPath = FILE_PATH_TO_QUEUES_DIR + File.separator + zipDir;

    try {
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        Path path = Paths.get(dirPath);
        path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                String fileName = event.context().toString();
                if (fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'), fileName.length()).equals(".7z")) {
                   //switch block here                    

                    break;
                }
            }
            key.reset();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is monitoring directory and when .7z file appeared there it will start to work on this file accordint to the `ImportOption` enum. And the method is used as: `Utils.monitorDirectory`. So I never create instance of the object which is containing this method (So maybe here is the issue with this code)

Comment: After short searching I've found [Seven Ways to Refactor Java switch Statements](https://www.developer.com/java/data/seven-ways-to-refactor-java-switch-statements.html). Might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this. I propose 2 options which are similar in terms of readability etc.

#### Option 1

Based on the information you've given (and assuming each of your `doSomething()`s are doing something different), I would just maintain a map containing the methods to launch for each option. I assume here that the options are in an `enum`, but the same principle applies if the options are integers or Strings.

```
private static final EnumMap<ExitCode, Runnable> runOnOption = new EnumMap<> (ExitCode.class);

static {
  runOnOption.put(ERROR, () -> LOG.error("an error occurred"));
  runOnOption.put(SUCCESS, () -> LOG.info("success"));
  runOnOption.put(FATAL, this::runOnFatal);
}

private static void runOnFatal() {
  //more complex recovery code
}
```

Then your main method becomes:

```
Runnable r = runOnOption(option);
if (r == null) throw new AssertionError("Missing option: " + option);
r.run();
```

---

#### Option 2

An alternative is to place the behaviour directly in the `enum`:

```
public enum ExitCode {
  ERROR(() -> LOG.error("an error occured")),
  SUCCESS(() -> LOG.info("success")),
  FATAL(() -> {
    //more complex code here
  };

  private final Runnable r;
  ExitCode(Runnable r) { this.r = r; }

  public void log() { r.run(); }
}
```

And your main code becomes:

```
option.log();
```

Comment: I will try to provide more information seems semi ok for my current implementation.

Comment: First thing, I would not like to block passing parameters to the method which will be run inside of case. I am not sure how could I by able to pass parameters

Comment: @Suule Instead of `Runnable` you can use a `Consumer<ParameterType>` or a `BiComsumer<Type1, Type2>` or a custom interface if you need more params.